# Consuming asynchronously data in WebApi controller action with PushStreamContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'd like to verify if this is the correct usage from WebAPI perspective of an asynchronous consumption of a data set.

Similar implementation tha creates an `IQueryable<T>` extension can be seen **[here](http://philsversion.com/2011/09/07/async-entity-framework-queries/)**.

My `GetByProcedureAsync()` uses the idea to create SqlDataReader like this:
`var result = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync<SqlDataReader>(cmd.BeginExecuteReader(), cmd.EndExecuteReader);`

I need to consume this in a MVC WebApi controller action. I don't know enough to quickly judge if I am hampering the async nature of the design.

Do I do `public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int key)` or `public async  Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri] int key)` in this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int key)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var set = await MyRepo.GetByProcedureAsync("PROC_NAME", key);
            // set is IEnumerable<MyEntity>
            foreach (MyEntity p in set)
            {
                var buffer = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p.ToString());
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close output stream as we are done 
            stream.Close();
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

Note that underlying sproc is observing the requirements to NOT push anything else to client before relevant record set.

Comment: Have you considered using EF6?

Comment: `IQueryable` is an inherently synchronous interface, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do makes much sense.

Comment: Also, be aware that `PushStreamContent` doesn't seem to understand `async` lambdas. That means you're creating an `async void` lambda, and you should be extremely careful with those (most of the time, they don't work as you would expect).

Comment: @StephenCleary, yes, but can't immediately.

Comment: @svick, I have been looking at the code and it looks like I should not have mentioned IQueryable because the the code goes directly against the database (with a stored procedure and an async reader).

Comment: By the time I manage to ask a question that makes sense, I will uncover its answer :-). I have made the edits to remove EF and `IQueryable<T>` from the picture